# I cant make my python server run with my IPV 4 address

Tags: python, sockets, server

```
import socket

PORT = 5050
SERVER = "Insert my public IPV4 address here"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)  #here is the line I get the error for
```

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "The Directory", line 15, in <module>
    server.bind(ADDR)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Can I not use my IPV4 to make the server public?
If not then what do I use?

Comment: You can't bind to your public address if you're behind NAT. You'd need to setup port forwarding on the router to forward incoming traffic to your computer, then `bind` to either `0.0.0.0`, or an address associated with an interface on your machine.

Comment: How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Assuming you're on a home network, that depends on your router. There's usually a "port forwarding" section under Network Management or some other header, then you tell it to forward traffic to the computer at your local address. If you google "port forwarding", you should be able to find quite a lot on the topic.

Comment: As this is a networking issue and not a programming issue, any further questions on setting up the port forwarding should be directed to [sf].

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think they'd accept it there since it's about a home networking setup. I think this would need to go on Super User instead.

Comment: Actually, I guess I'm assuming it's on a home network. In my experience though, if there's any whiff of a question being about anything other than "professional" networking setups, it's closed on Network Engineering/Server Fault.

Comment: @Carcigenicate there are tons of questions on [sf] related to home networking, it is not just for corporate systems.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That may be, but their tour says "Don't ask about... Anything in a home or development environment".

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok, you win: "*Server Fault is a question and answer site for managing information technology systems **in a business environment**.*" [su] it is, then.